# Resize textarea as well as the div -- but to the same scale as the div is resized to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

```
$( "#panel" ).resizable({
        animate: true,
        ghost: true
    });
```

Hello, I have this javascript code (above), and this html code (below):

```
<div id=panel><br><form action="postit.php" method="post" name="post" style = "margin-left:40px;">
<textarea required cols="35" rows="5" name="status" style = "max-width: 500px; max-height: 150px;  width: 95%; opacity: 1;" class="resizable" id = "statuses">
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Status!"/>
</form></div>
```

So what code must I put to make it also resize the textarea to the same scale as the div resizes to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With percentages.

```
<textarea id="textarea" style="width:50%; height:50%;">
```

[Watch in Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TAaH8/9/)